# how to fetch json data in angularjs repeat directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to know that, how should i fetch the **main menu** from my json file in ng-repeat separately and sub menus separately.

Below are my files

> menu.json

```
{"data":
    {
        "main menu":
        {
            "menu1":
            [
                {"id":1, "name":"level 2", "body":"this is a body."},
                {"id":2, "name":"something new", "body":"this is a body new."}
            ],
            "menu2":
            [
                {"id":1, "name":"cobat_something", "body":"this is a body of cobat."},
                {"id":2, "name":"cobat_something new", "body":"this is a body of cobat new."}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

here is my js file

> app.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('mainController', ['$http', function($http){
        var mainCtrl = this;
        $http.get('menu.json').success(function(data){
            mainCtrl.menus = data;
        });
    }]);

})();
```

and this is my html file

> index.html

```
    <body ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="menu in mainCtrl.menus">
        {{menu}}
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="subMenu in mainCtrl.menus">
            {{subMenu.main menu}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    </body>
```

Comment: you have `"main menu":` twice in your json, the last one is going to overwrite the first one

Comment: Just replase `<li ng-repeat="subMenu in mainCtrl.menus">` to `<li ng-repeat="subMenu in menu">` becuse you are in the scope of `menu`

Comment: In your controller: `mainCtrl.menus = data.data["main menu"];`, and in your html do `ng-repeat="(menuName, menus) in mainCtrl.menus"` followed by `ng-repeat="menu in menus"`.

Comment: add ng-app="myApp" to your body !

Comment: @jperezov   Hi sir, first of all Thank you... You solved my problem....   :)  ....  can you please explain me what is inside the brackets  like  this line      ------------        (menuName, menus) in mainCtrl.menus

Comment: @AkshayKumar sure thing. That line is the equivalent of `(index, value)`. It'll store the index, whether it's numeric or a string, in the first variable, and the value / object is stored in the second variable.

Comment: @jperezov   Thankyou sir

Answer (score 0):

Try like below to list the menu names.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menus in mainCtrl.menus">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="menu in menus">
          {{menu.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Angular Code:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('mainController', ['$http', function($http) {
    var mainCtrl = this;
    $http.get('menu.json').success(function(response) {
      mainCtrl.menus = response.data["main menu"];
    });
  }]);

})();
```